# Error while building: could not resolve index2.js SvelteKit

Tags: node.js, build, vite, sveltekit

When I try running `npm run build` or `npm run build -- --force` after everything is built and tries to run `@sveltejs/adapter-node` I get the following error:

```bash
Run npm run preview to preview your production build locally.

> Using @sveltejs/adapter-node
error during build:
RollupError: Could not resolve "../../chunks/index2.js" from ".svelte-kit/adapter-node/entries/pages/_page.svelte.js"
    at error (file:///E:/Code/Projects/tilt-design-2/node_modules/rollup/dist/es/shared/node-entry.js:2124:30)
    at ModuleLoader.handleInvalidResolvedId (file:///E:/Code/Projects/tilt-design-2/node_modules/rollup/dist/es/shared/node-entry.js:23990:24)
    at ModuleLoader.resolveDynamicImport (file:///E:/Code/Projects/tilt-design-2/node_modules/rollup/dist/es/shared/node-entry.js:24048:58)  
    at async file:///E:/Code/Projects/tilt-design-2/node_modules/rollup/dist/es/shared/node-entry.js:23937:32
```

I think I set up everything correctly and here are my configs if it helps:

`vite.config.ts`:

```
import { sveltekit } from '@sveltejs/kit/vite';
import { defineConfig } from 'vitest/config';

export default defineConfig({
    plugins: [sveltekit()],
    test: {
        include: ['src/**/*.{test,spec}.{js,ts}']
    }
});
```

`svelte.config.js`:

```js
import adapter from '@sveltejs/adapter-node';
import { vitePreprocess } from '@sveltejs/kit/vite';

/** @type {import('@sveltejs/kit').Config} */
const config = {
    // Consult https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/integrations#preprocessors
    // for more information about preprocessors
    preprocess: vitePreprocess(),
    kit: {
        // adapter-auto only supports some environments, see https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/adapter-auto for a list.
        // If your environment is not supported or you settled on a specific environment, switch out the adapter.
        // See https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/adapters for more information about adapters.
        adapter: adapter()
    }
};

export default config;
```